# Removing NSNotificationCenter Observers from iOS 9

Tags: ios9, nsnotificationcenter, observers

**From iOS 9** it is no longer necessary for an `NSNotificationCenter` observer to un-register itself when being deallocated, it's done *automatically*.

Does this apply to `NSKeyValueObserving` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it's true for KVO as well.

Keep in mind that you should unregister key-value observers if you're targetting below iOS 9.